# Assign Vue Event Handler to Method's Return Value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**Problem:** I need to set a vue component's event handler equal to the return value of another method.

This JavaScript runs on click.

```html
<!-- pseudo code -->
<input type="button" @click="count + 1">
```

Method is invoked on click.

```html
<!-- pseudo code -->
<input type="button" @click="addToCount">
...
<script>
function addToCount () {
    count + 1
}
</script>
```

But this will invoke `getAddToCountHandler` on click, not `addToCount`.

```html
<!-- pseudo code -->
<input type="button" @click="getAddToCountHandler()">
...
<script>
function getAddToCountHandler () {
    return function addToCount () {
        count + 1
    }
}
</script>
```

The following is closer to what I am trying to do, with some variables stored in a closure.

```html
<!-- pseudo code -->
<input type="button" @click="getHandler(0)">
...
<script>
function getHandler (param) {
    let storedParam = param
    return function () {
        storedParam += 1
        console.log(storedParam)
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should run the return function as follows by adding `()` like :

```
<input type="button" @click="getAddToCountHandler()()">
```

or

```
function getAddToCountHandler () {
    return function addToCount () {
        count + 1
    }()
}
```

```js
let app=new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:function() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
   getAddToCountHandler() {
   let that=this;
      return function addToCount() {
      console.log(that.count)
        that.count =that.count+1
      }()
    }

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="button" @click="getAddToCountHandler()" value="increment" /> {{count}}
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, Boussadjra, my question was incomplete. I've edited it to add context for you.

Comment: but what' the exact issue ?

Comment: Looking at the last script I added to my question, there is a closure with state I want to maintain throughout the lifespan of the click handler. Given your answer, that closure and handler is recreated, and the closure's state reset, each time the button is clicked.